# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to \infty} (e^{\frac{1}{x}}(x^3 - x^2 + \frac{x}{2}) - \sqrt{x^6 +1})$ using Taylor

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\left[e^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(x^3 - x^2 + \dfrac{x}{2}\right) - \sqrt{x^6 +1}\right]$
(I assume that we need to use $t = \frac{1}{x}$ in order to get lim, where argument goes to $0$.  But for now I'm not doing this since it won't help much at this moment).

$- \sqrt{x^6 + 1} = -\left( 1 + \dfrac{x^6}{2} + r_n (x)\right)$
Hence, we need somehow get $\frac{x^6}{2}$ from the $e^{\frac{1}{x}}(x^3 - x^2 + \frac{x}{2})$
Doesn't matter what I've tried, after expressing $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ as Taylor polynomial max degree of any positive term is $3$.
Of course, I can multiply this term with $x^3$, but then I have infinity in nominator, which is not good. I don't know how to cancel $- \frac{x^6}{2}$ with something.
Also after multiplication of $e^{\frac{1}{x}}$ in polynomial form by $(x^3 - x^2 + \frac{x}{2})$ I get $x^3$ which, again, doesn't cancel with anything.
Multiply-divide by conjugate method helps a bit, but then there is "unsolvable" expression in denominator.

Am I doing something wrong?
If you've got another results, please, share

Comment: You should try the $t = 1/x$ substitution if you intend to use Taylor series. Even if the Taylor series converges there is no guarantee of uniform convergence on an unbounded interval (meaning you can't really use them for an infinite limit)

Comment: This step is completely wrong $$\sqrt{x^6 + 1} = ( 1 + \frac{x^6}{2} + r_n (x))$$ Let consider instead $$\sqrt{x^6 +1} = x^3\left(1+\frac1{x^6}\right)^\frac12$$ and use Taylor for $\left(1+\frac1{x^6}\right)^\frac12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1+\frac1x+\frac1{2x^2}+\frac1{6x^3} +o\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)$$

$$\sqrt{x^6 +1} = x^3\left(1+\frac1{x^6}\right)^\frac12= x^3+\frac12\frac1{x^3}+o\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)$$

and then

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}}\left(x^3 - x^2 + \frac{x}{2}\right) - \sqrt{x^6 +1}=$$

$$=x^3 - x^2 + \frac{x}{2}+x^2 - x + \frac{1}{2}+\frac x2 - \frac12 + \frac16- x^3+o(1)=$$

$$=\frac 1 6+o(1)\to \frac16$$